# Find the minimum number of non-interescting lines from a matrix in R

Tags: r, math, matrix

I have a set of lines some of which intersect each other. I can generate an intercept matrix.

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6
1   0   1   0   1   0   0
2   1   0   1   1   0   0
3   0   1   0   0   1   0
4   1   1   0   0   0   1
5   0   0   1   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Where 1 = intersects and 0 = does not itersect

For example line 1 intersects with lines 2 and 4.

I would like to produce the minimum number of sets of lines where no lines intersect within the set.

For this example, the best I could come up with is three sets containing:

lines 2, 5, 6

lines 1,3

line 4

I'm programming this in R but I really need a mathematical/conceptional answer to the problem.

Comment: You could change the diag element to a default value. then do `apply(df, 1, function(x) which(x==0))`.

Comment: Why isn't any other singleton set (other than 4) in your solution? For example, a set with only line 1 also has (trivially) no lines intersect within the set. Also, any pair of lines for which your matrix is 0 is also part of the solution. Also, (1,5,6).

Comment: @aichao the solution I gave was just an example, I'm sure there are others, but I couldn't find one with less than 3 sets. For my task, the composition of the sets does not matter as long as the don't intersect and there are as few as possible.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the lines as nodes in a graph and the intersection relation as edges (i.e. your matrix is the adjacency matrix), then you want to assign every vertex to a group, such that two neighboring vertices are not in the same group.

This is equivalent to the vertex coloring problem. A number of algorithms for this problem can be found on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Algorithms). The problem of finding the optimal coloring is NP-hard. If you are good with an approximation, you can use the greedy approach with a time complexity of O(V D), where V is the number of vertices and D is the maximum vertex degree.